# How do I display all values of a Django Model record?

Tags: python, django

In rails I am able to say:

```
painting = Painting.first
painting.attributes
```

And this will automatically display all the model's values.  Is there an equivalent in Django to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `dir(painting)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Django in particular, but using python you can try one of the following:

```
painting.__dict__
vars(painting)
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't understand very well, but if you wanna [see all the values from a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) use this

```
list(your_model.objects.values_list())
```

if you wanna see the [fields information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) use

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User._meta.get_fields()
(<ManyToOneRel: admin.logentry>,
 <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: password>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: last_login>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_superuser>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: username>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: first_name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: last_name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.EmailField: email>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_staff>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_active>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: date_joined>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: groups>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: user_permissions>)
```

read the docs for more information